# How can I evaluate this complex integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

So I have this integral *I*,
$$I = 1=\int_0^L  Nx^\alpha(L-x)^\beta dx$$ where $\alpha$,$\beta$, and $L$ > 0 and $N$ is a normalization constant. For the case $\alpha = \frac{7}{2}$ and $\beta=\frac{5}{2}$, I am tasked to find *N*. I know that in solving this integral, I just have to treat *N* and *L* as constants. However, I am still having a hard time getting the correct answer since my initial approach was to distribute $Nx^\alpha$ to $(L-x)^\beta$ but considering the exponents, this might not be possible. Can anyone show me another perspective on how to do this problem?

Comment: Try $x=L \sin^2(t)$

Comment: ... or you may try $x=lt\Rightarrow I=L^{\alpha+\beta+1}N\int_0^1 t^\alpha(1-t)^\beta dt$

Comment: @Svyatoslav will I do integration by parts after getting that expression?

Comment: Sorry, made a typo: meant $x=Lt$. If L is the constant - just make this change of variable, and also change the limits of integration accordingly: if $x\in[0,L], \, t=(x/L) \in [0,1]$

Comment: @Svyatoslav At first I was confused but then I realized it might have been a typo so no worries. I tried doing your method because you were able to bring out the constant *L*. But I still got stuck after simplifying it to $NL^7 \int_0^1 t^{\frac{7}{2}} \left (1-t\right)^\frac{5}{2}dt$. What should I do after this? Is integration by parts a viable option with $u=\left(1-t\right)^\frac{5}{2}$ and $dv=t^{\frac{7}{2}}$?

Comment: You may try the change $x=sin^2(t)$ - as @Claude Leibovici suggested, and will get the integral with $\sin^m(t)\cos^n(t)$, were $m,n$ - integres. A shortcut is to use beta-function:$\int_0^1 t^{\alpha-1} \left (1-t\right)^{\beta-1} dt=B(\alpha, \beta)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}$